# Copy a file from argument and rename

Tags: bash

Hello I realize this may be simple for most but I cannot figure out how to copy a file an input parameters inside a script. I want to take the input and copy that existing file and add .bak to it. this is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
  cp $1 $1.bak
```

Comment: That `$1` in the second line shouldn't be there, but `cp "$1" "$1".bak` should work fine.

Comment: @muru Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

That `$1` in the second line shouldn't be there, but `cp "$1" "$1".bak` should work fine. Always remember to quote your variables, so that spaces and other special characters don't create problems.